# Deploy GWT project to Web-sphere

Tags: java, gwt, websphere

how to deploy GWT project to Web-Sphere? I have assemble an .war file, it consist same files as located in project's "war" folder.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you WAR is assembled [properly](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html) (btw, how do you assemble it?), then using the [WebSphere admin console.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/tasks/tdpdeploying_war_assets_entire.htm)